# Save multiple sheets to PDF with loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

For illustrative purposes, i have  a workbook with 6 sheets ("A-MASTER","A-1","A-2","B-MASTER","B-1","B-2"). My goal is to have a VBA loop that -

1. Extracts and saves "A-MASTER","A-1","A-2" as a workbook/pdf and "B-MASTER","B-1","B-2" as another workbook/pdf
2. The name of the new workbook will be the name of the first sheet in each "Set"

Final result should be 2 workbooks named "A-Master" and "B-Master", both containing 3 sheets

Having trouble writing out the loop, could someone kindly provide guidance?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please include the code you are trying to use in your question. You can use the `Left$` function to check the first digit of the sheet name to know when to save and start a new PDF.

Comment: There are several Q&A on here and even some with code and at least one with one master sheet with 6 slave sheets... on my smartphone with low battery so you can look for them.